# what the the fastest way to save multi-layer map?

Tags: c++, stl, bit-manipulation, unordered-map

I want to build a key-value container to save data.

i can build a three-level `unordered_map` to map it, the key will be `<int, <int, <int>>>`, but i think it's slow.

So, I want to map `<int, int, int>` into a unique `int`. then i can save it in one-level `unordered_map`

For example:

assume the three key is called `a, b, c`, a's range is `[0, 1e4]`, b `[0, 1e6]` c `[0, 1e5]`

i want to wirte a function like this:

```
int encode(int a, int b, int c) {
  // return a unique int
}
```

i am very time sensitive, and i think bitwise maybe the fastest way,but i cant figure out how to realize it. can you help on this?

And do you think this will be faster? and, is there any methods can do better than this?

Comment: I'm too lazy to check if 1e15 fits into an int64_t. If it does, there's your answer. Modern multi-Ghz CPUs won't have any issues doing the multiplication and addition without breaking a sweat.

Comment: You need a minimum of 51 bits to do a simple bitwise packing of these numbers so that won't fit in a 32-bit integer. The best you could do with a decimal packing would be 50 bits

Comment: Have you profiled simply storing the 3 integers as keys and use `a ^ b ^ c` as hash?

Comment: @Meowmere: "Have you profiled" - that's premature pessimisation - measurement's not warranted before concluding that's a god-awful choice.  Even if being lazy, it's nuts not to at least use something like  `(a << 9) ^ (a >> 2) & (b << 7) ^ (b >> 3) ^ (c << 7) ^ (c >> 4)`, where bits from each input affect a couple positions in the hash value, equal values don't cancel each other out, and all permutations of a, b and c don't all yield the same hash value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unordered_map` expects a hash function returning `size_t`, so if you're compiling a 64-bit application (as most people do except in some embedded environments), you can combine the integers trivially:

```
size_t encode(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + (b * 10'000) + (c * 10'000 * 1'000'000);
}
```

If your hash table uses a prime number of buckets (e.g. GCC, clang), you could consider rounding the above numbers up to the nearest powers of 2, as nominally multiplying by a power of two is a simple left-bit-shift operation that the CPU can do faster.  If your implementation uses power-of-2 bucket counts (e.g. Visual C++) then you should avoid that at all costs: as when modding numbers into a power-of-2 bucket count the high order bits are discarded.  For example, if you have 256 buckets, the 8 least-significant bits determine the bucket and the more-signiciant bits are discarded.

Alternatively, you could use the algorithm adopted by `boost::hash_combine`, which is generally useful for hashing multi-part keys:

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= hasher(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
size_t encode(int a, int b, int c) {
    size_t seed = 0;
    hash_combine(seed, a);
    hash_combine(seed, b);
    hash_combine(seed, c);
    return seed;
}
```

Yet another option is to arrange the bytes side-by-side in memory (e.g. copy them into a variable - `int x[3]{ a, b, c};`), and apply any hash function written to hash an arbitrary block of memory, i.e. `size_t (const std::byte* p, size_t n)` - googling will turn up plenty.